# How to surface error in QueueBase#initialize?

Tags: google-cast

When implementing a custom queue, what is the best way to handle error? The documentation shows how to [surface error in load message interceptor](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver/core_features#error_handling), but not how to surface error in [`QueueBase#intialize`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.QueueBase#initialize).

When load message interceptor returns or throws an [`ErrorData`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.messages.ErrorData), [`cast.framework.events.EventType.ERROR`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.events.ErrorEvent) will fire. But when `QueueBase#initialize` returns or throws an `ErrorData` (or any instance of `Error`, really), `cast.framework.events.EventType.ERROR` does not fire, which makes it impossible to handle those error.